# iOS - some questions about present and push the controllers

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

There are three controllers here, `AViewController`, `BViewController`, `CViewController`,
the first step: `AViewController` present to `BViewController`;

```
BViewController *BVC = [[BViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:BVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The second step: `BViewController` push to `CViewController`;

```
CViewController *CVC = [[CViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:CVC];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Now, if I want to go back from `CViewController` to `AViewController`, what code should I write?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

to dismiss C ViewController, because C ViewController is now on the Navigation Stack. A present a navigation controller that contain B ViewController. B ViewController push C ViewController, so C is still in Navigation Controller.

You can look at my project here:

https://github.com/khuong291/TestTransition

[image]

Comment: if i want to do these in one step,how can i do ?

Comment: Wait me a minute, I will create a new project for you easy to see.

Comment: It's simple, you can convert it to objective-c, have you run my project yet?

Comment: I have just added a gif file for you easy to see the result

Comment: i have run your projrct,it's great ,and this problem i have solved,but now , i have new problems.
 
now, i need to present BViewController which does not have the navigation bar from AViewController,and i need to push CViewController which has navigation form BViewController.

Comment: i need set BViewController translucent,and i can see the things on the AViewController from BViewController.what code should i write?

Comment: First, if my answer solve your question, please mark it a correct answer for someone outside know. Then I will continue to help you :)

Comment: You can set view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5) in B viewDidLoad()

Comment: I don't know a lot with this, but you can use BlurView instead, googling and find the solution :D

Comment: No problem, glad it help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should present `BViewController` like this:

```
BViewController *BVC = [[BViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:BVC];
//Setting For Transparent
nav.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
nav.definesPresentationContext = YES;
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and in BViewController implement:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];


}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```

And you can push to `CViewController`:

```
CViewController *CVC = [[CViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:CVC animated:YES];
```

And when you want back to A. Simple call it in C:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: if there are DViewController,EViewController,FViewController,is it still work??

Comment: You can look at my project for you easy to understand.

Comment: now, i need to present BViewController which does not have the navigation bar from AViewController,and i need to push CViewController which has  navigation form BViewController.and your way doesn't work

Comment: where can i find your project?

Comment: Look at my answer :|

Comment: @yulingsong Just add two function to B - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    
    
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
eveything will be ok :D

Comment: your way is work.but now i need set BViewController translucent,and i can see the things on the AViewController from BViewController.what code should i write?

Comment: @yulingsong check my edit answer. Setting like this and in B controller you can set alpha decrease from 1 so you can see A through B

Comment: i have set the  alpha of the BviewController for 0.5,and backgroundColor is black,but i still can't see the thing on AViewController

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];

Comment: @yulingsong do you set it :BVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
BVC.definesPresentationContext = YES;
BVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

Comment: wait for me 30 minutes,i'm going to having lunch now.when i come back ,we talk about it again.thanks

Comment: i'm back here.can we go on

Comment: @yulingsong https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdmnobbmdotc8vq/TestCodeSwift.zip?dl=0 It is your code, you can download my demo with swift. Np here.

Comment: @yulingsong Check my editAnswer. Maybe it work for you.